# Data not updated after commiting the transaction

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, netbeans, eclipselink

I'm using Jpa to manipulate a mysql database;
I bind every boolean property to checkbox, so that when i check/uncheck it, the state of the property will change..

An idea how my application looks like:
[image]

The Jtable in the screen it's also binded to a `java.util.list< Eleve >`, so updates are synchronized between Jtable and list(observable).

This is basically my Eleve entity:

```
public class Eleve implements Serializable {
    ...
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "si", nullable = false)
    private boolean si;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ci", nullable = false)
    private boolean ci;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "pi", nullable = false)
    private boolean pi;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "gi", nullable = false)
    private boolean gi;
    ...
```

My problem is **sometimes** after checking some check-boxes, persisting and then committing a transaction(update) the new state isn't updated in the Database without showing any error message..

**EDIT**
I made a test as suggested by @ wrschneider99, the strange problem is the property is successfully set to True.. So there is no memory problem..
I'll try to change the database to H2 and try to reproduce this bug...

Any suggestion?
Cheers.

Comment: have you isolated to the JPA / persistence layer?  Are you positive that the state of your `List<Eleve>` is what you want it to be, before persistence?

Comment: "have you isolated to the JPA" No, i'm making a bit change of the crud generated by netbeans.. this is not a good practice, but i didn't thought that will affect application behavior. "Are you positive that the state of your List<Eleve> is what you want it to be, before persistence?", Thank you for asking that I'll check this..

Comment: Please see my update..Any other thing must be checked?

Comment: How are you checking that it isn't in the database (via checking the database, or by reading an entity somewhere else)?.  Try turning logging on to finest to see what is logged for your transaction, and show how you are persisting the changes.  You might also try performing a find after your persist/merge and verify the state of the managed entity before the transaction commits- does it show the changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, i'm using two different EntityManger, let's says, `em1` and `em2`.

What i made in my code is retrieving all entities from Database using em1(at the startup of application), and then when i make a filter(looking for a sub list of Eleve) i'm using the **em2**, so that when I check some check-boxes the `boolean` property changes in the memory but `em1` don't know about this change.

```
  java.util.Collection<Eleve> data = ejc.findEleveByNiveauClasseNomPrenom(niv, classe, nom, prenom);
```

So I passed `em1` in the parameter of my function:

```
 java.util.Collection<Eleve> data = ejc.findEleveByNiveauClasseNomPrenom(niv, classe, nom, prenom,em1);
```

And now it's working fine.